# In Google Sheets, is there a way to output the values of the last month listed in each year in a table of monthly data spanning many years?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a table of raw financial data telling me what the value of an account was at the end of a given month (denoted in the date format `MM/1/YY` to normalize). There are multiple years worth of data in this table such that I may have something like this (please ignore the exact values, they are just placeholder):

```
1/1/18  $123
2/1/18  $21
3/1/18  $34
4/1/18  $45
5/1/18  $76
6/1/18  $1
7/1/18  $123
8/1/18  $4343
9/1/18  $2
10/1/18 $53
11/1/18 $123
12/1/18 $12
1/1/19  $213
2/1/19  $123
3/1/19  $34
4/1/19  $123
```

I'd like to create an array (or ideally a pivot) using this data such that it will summarize what the last value in a given year was, including partial years.

So for the above, it would output:

```
12/1/18 $12
4/1/19 $123
```

Or even better...do the cleaning up of formatting to change it to just the full year:

```
2018 $12
2019 $123
```

When I attempt to pivot the raw data, none of the "Summarize By" options seem to result in the desired output.

The raw data table is expected to grow in length over time, so the ideal solution stays current without needing manual updates. Thus, as the table grew to 2020, it would just add that more recent month's value from that year to the end of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(YEAR(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)))), 
 QUERY(SORT({A1:A,B1:B}, 1,0,2,0), "select year(Col1),Col2"), {1,2}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This worked, but I'm having trouble following what this is doing. Can you break it down for me?

Comment: sure... its a simple `VLOOKUP` where in first parameter we do unique of years in A column (`indirect` is needed coz blank cells would be accounted too as year 1890). then 2nd `vlookup` parameter is query where we control output to be years instead of dtes hence `year(Col1)`  that `sort` in `query` input is just a safety measure if you would have more dates in month or more amounts for same date... eg. to assure that you will always get the latest of the latest

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, you can do these using Sortn to sort on year using option 2 (ignore duplicates):

```
=sortn(sort(filter({year(A:A),A:B},A:A<>""),2,false),999,2,1,true)
```

The data is pre-sorted descending on date (using sort), so sortn picks out the row with most recent date in each year.

[image]

**Breakdown of steps**

(1) Add year to data using {} notation. Note this converts blank cells to 1899, which will have to be removed:

```
{year(A:A),A:B}
```

[image]

(2) Filter out blank cells:

```
filter({year(A:A),A:B},A:A<>"")
```

[image]

(3) Sort in descending order of date:

```
sort(filter({year(A:A),A:B},A:A<>""),2,false)
```

[image]

(4) Sort in ascending order of year, but dropping all dates except the first (most recent) in each year:

```
=sortn(sort(filter({year(A:A),A:B},A:A<>""),2,false),999,2,1,true)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble following what this is doing. Can you break it down for me?

Comment: OK, will add to my answer.